# node.js - static content via apache? not found via node

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache

I'm new to node.js just playing around with socket and node.

I've this server:

```
var fs = require('fs')
    , http = require('http')
    , socketio = require('socket.io');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/index.html'));
}).listen(1234, function() {
    console.log('Listening at: http://localhost:1234');
});

socketio.listen(server).on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('message', function (msg) {
        console.log('Message Received: ', msg);
        socket.broadcast.emit('message', msg);
    });
});
```

I see it doesn't load normal html static content, like css and js files from server.js folder.

How do I make node.js load these?

Or how do I rewrite my server, so that index.html is served by apache and all the message pinging is done with node?

Comment: Add express and use the [static route](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use) built in.

Comment: @adeneo what about apache way? I'd prefer to serve static content with it. Maybe use php somewhere in-between too. How do I redirect socket.io requests?

Comment: Why use Apache when you can use Node ?

Comment: @adeneo I want to use php library? need node.js + socket.io only for pushing notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are making a simple site, with not much static content, you can send it all with node + express.  If your site is heavy on images/video/etc, then having apache to deal with those things is a good solution.  Just remember that node and apache can't both listen on port 80.  Set up apache to listen on port 80, then use mod_proxy (the [P] flag in htaccess) to redirect requests you want going to node over a different port.

Comment: How do I redirect websocket requests? Port issue is clear to me, I just don't seem to understand how websocket works in case of apache.

Comment: Sockets use their own port, no need to redirect them.

Comment: Yes, but if I'm on apache served page, how does node.js know what is happening on a page served via ap?

Comment: Read about sockets.io and you'll see.